# How to Call Captcha Action in Yii Framework to create image

Tags: yii

I have app in Yii framework and i want to add Captcha in it and i don't want use Yii defaults .. long story short , i found one which works fine without framework so i created an action and i put image creation function in it, but when i call that action i get broken link.

> yii/mycontroller/createcaptchaimage

What is wrong in my solution ?

the captha code is in this [link](http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_4/article_243-simple-php-captcha-script.htm) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your solution. You Obviously have some Routing issue . Did you checked your main.php or .htaccess ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this captcha-extended extension more beautiful than CCapthcha. Here is the link:

> http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/captcha-extended/

You call it just like normal CCaptcha widget from any view/layout file:

```
<?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
```

This will look for controller action "captcha" which is defined in array of actions.

```
public function actions(){
    return array(
        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CaptchaExtendedAction',
            // if needed, modify settings
            'mode'=>CaptchaExtendedAction::MODE_MATH,
        ),
    );
}
```